# How to keep React components state after browser refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

Thank you reading my first question.

I trying to auth With Shared Root use react, react-router and firebase.
So, I want to keep `App.js` 's user state. but when I tried to refresh the browser, user state was not found.

I've tried to save to localstorage. But is there a way to keep state on component after browser refresh without `localStorage`?

---

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import Rebase from 're-base'

import auth from './config/auth'

const base = Rebase.createClass('https://myapp.firebaseio.com')

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: auth.loggedIn(),
      user: {}
    }
  }

  _updateAuth (loggedIn, user) {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: !!loggedIn,
      user: user
    })
  }

   componentWillMount () {
     auth.onChange = this._updateAuth.bind(this)
     auth.login() // save localStorage
   }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.children &&
          React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
            user: this.state.user
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
App.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.any
}
```

**auth.js**

```
import Rebase from 're-base'
const base = Rebase.createClass('https://myapp.firebaseio.com')

export default {
  loggedIn () {
    return !!base.getAuth()
  },

  login (providers, cb) {
    if (Boolean(base.getAuth())) {
      this.onChange(true, this.getUser())
      return
    }

    // I think this is weird...
    if (!providers) {
      return
    }

    base.authWithOAuthPopup(providers, (err, authData) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Login Failed!', err)
      } else {
        console.log('Authenticated successfully with payload: ', authData)
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({
          name: base.getAuth()[providers].displayName,
          icon: base.getAuth()[providers].profileImageURL
        }))
        this.onChange(true, this.getUser())
        if (cb) { cb() }
      }
    })
  },
  logout (cb) {
    base.unauth()
    localStorage.clear()
    this.onChange(false, null)
    if (cb) { cb() }
  },
  onChange () {},
  getUser: function () { return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) }
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import auth from './config/auth.js'

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor (props, context) {
    super(props)
  }

  _login (authType) {
    auth.login(authType, data => {
      this.context.router.replace('/authenticated')
    })
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='login'>
        <button onClick={this._login.bind(this, 'twitter')}>Login with Twitter account</button>
        <button onClick={this._login.bind(this, 'facebook')}>Login with Facebook account</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
Login.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you reload the page through a browser refresh, your component tree and state will reset to initial state.

To restore a previous state after a page reload in browser, you have to

- save state locally (localstorage/[IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API))
- and/ or at server side to reload.

And build your page in such a way that on initialisation, a check is made for previously saved local state and/or server state, and if found, the previous state will be restored.

Comment: wintvelt, Thank you for your answer. I solved using localstorage!

Comment: @wintvelt  is this a propper aproach , dont u think this will cause to security reasons . ?

Comment: @Mr.G Yes, security (and privacy) is something that you need to take into account. If Firebase is used, then a browser refresh will check again the logged in state with Firebase, so Firebase will handle that part of the security. In general, component UI state like which page is open, which dropdowns are open, filters, checkboxes, contents of fields in forms (non-username/ password), etc are usually less sensitive and could be stored locally. Personally, I only store locally for state that is not behind a user login. And store on server (more secure) only state for authenticated users.